# Installed PWA is not running the notification request permission promise. Why is that?

Tags: android, laravel, vue.js, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app (made of laravel+inertia) that has function which the user receive notification if the user enable it. This web app has a PWA implemented to it. My problem is when I installed the PWA version of the web application on my mobile phone the notification permission dialog box will not appear but when I uninstalled the PWA version of it and access the web application on the mobile browser only the notification permission dialog box will appear. Why is that? And can anyone help me resolve this bug/error? TIA

I`ve tried asking chatgpt regarding this and all of its recommended solution doesnt work.